# Issue with Delphi FireMonkey Visual Component Integration

Tags: delphi, components, firemonkey, delphi-11-alexandria

I have developed a class that I intend to use as a visual component within the Delphi FireMonkey framework. After installing the class via a package and adding the visual component to a form, everything appears as expected within the visual component. When I save the form, there are no errors, and everything is correctly written to the .fmx file (as I need to work in the FireMonkey environment).

However, when I switch between the design and code tabs within the RAD Studio, I encounter error messages. Additionally, when attempting to run the application, I also encounter errors. Error is "can not find Class TMySpeedbutton".

I've included some code below that can reproduce this behavior. Could anyone provide suggestions on where my issue might be? Just save the Code as a Unit, paste it inside a new Component and Install the Component.

```
unit uMyVisualLayout;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Layouts, FMX.StdCtrls, FMX.Objects,
  FMX.Graphics;

Type
  TMyImage = class(TImage)

  private
    FBackupImage: TBitmap;

  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

Type
  TMySpeedbutton = class(TSpeedButton)

  private
    FLabelText: TLabel;
    function GetNewText: String;
    procedure SetNewText(const Value: String);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    property NewText: String read GetNewText write SetNewText;
  end;

Type
  TMyLayout = class(TLayout)

  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
    Speedbutton1, Speedbutton2, Speedbutton3: TMySpeedbutton;
    TopFlowLayout: TFlowLayout;
    procedure ButtonClick(Sender: Tobject);
  protected
    { Protected-Deklarationen }
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    { Public-Deklarationen }
  published
    { Published-Deklarationen }
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('TestVisualComponent', [TMyLayout]);
end;

{ TMyLayout }

procedure TMyLayout.ButtonClick(Sender: Tobject);
begin
  log.d(TSpeedButton(Sender).Name + ' Clicked!');
end;

constructor TMyLayout.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  TopFlowLayout := TFlowLayout.Create(self);
  TopFlowLayout.Parent := self;
  TopFlowLayout.Align := TAlignLayout.MostTop;

  Speedbutton1 := TMySpeedbutton.Create(self);
  Speedbutton1.Parent := TopFlowLayout;
  Speedbutton1.Align := TAlignLayout.Client;
  Speedbutton1.NewText := 'Speedbutton1';
  Speedbutton1.OnClick := ButtonClick;

  Speedbutton2 := TMySpeedbutton.Create(self);
  Speedbutton2.Parent := TopFlowLayout;
  Speedbutton2.Align := TAlignLayout.Client;
  Speedbutton2.NewText := 'Speedbutton2';
  Speedbutton2.OnClick := ButtonClick;

  Speedbutton3 := TMySpeedbutton.Create(self);
  Speedbutton3.Parent := TopFlowLayout;
  Speedbutton3.Align := TAlignLayout.Client;
  Speedbutton3.NewText := 'Speedbutton3';
  Speedbutton3.OnClick := ButtonClick;

end;

{ TMyImage }

constructor TMyImage.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FBackupImage := TBitmap.Create;
end;

destructor TMyImage.Destroy;
begin
  FBackupImage.Free;
  inherited;
end;

{ TMySpeedbutton }

constructor TMySpeedbutton.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FLabelText := TLabel.Create(self);
  FLabelText.Parent := self;
  FLabelText.Align := TAlignLayout.Client;
end;

destructor TMySpeedbutton.Destroy;
begin
  FLabelText.Free;
  inherited;
end;

function TMySpeedbutton.GetNewText: String;
begin
  Result := FLabelText.Text;
end;

procedure TMySpeedbutton.SetNewText(const Value: String);
begin
  FLabelText.Text := Value;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Similar [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30913607)

Comment: You need to add your `uMyVisualLayout` unit to search path for specific project in [Project > Options > Building > Delphi Compiler](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Delphi_Compiler) or 
to Browsing path in [Tools > Options > Language > Delphi Options > Library](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Library). Without this Delphi can't find suitable unit to add it into uses section after you have placed your visual component on the form.

Comment: As @BrakNicku suggests, set `TopFlowLayout.Stored:=False;`.

Comment: You're absolutely correct. The solution lies in combining the advice from both @BrakNicku and SilverWarior. However, I'm unsure about where I should place my units during the initial setup. My goal is to avoid having to modify the search path in the target project. Typically, when I work with components from other companies, there is often an installation script provided, or I have to create the BPLs (packages) manually. Most of the time, I don't need to make any changes to my target project. Do you have any suggestions or resources I can refer to on this topic? Thanks for your help!